# Graphics card not detected by Windows even though it was there a day ago

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

My NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 graphics card was working with no problems just until a day ago. Today when I opened my laptop and checked `Task Manager`, it was gone.

[image: No Discrete Graphics]

Naturally, I checked my Display Adapters from Device Manager to see what was happening. It had vanished from there as well.

[image: Gone]

At this point, I started panicking. I opened GeForce Experience to see if I could get any help from there. It listed the Studio Driver (which is the one I use) under `Available`. I clicked `Custom Installation`. After some time it came up with this:

[image: Incompatible Windows Version]

I tried with the `Express Installation` but it still yielded the same results.

I checked my Windows version, which was `1903`, the latest version.

[image: Windows version is the latest (i.e 1903) indeed]

To be clear here, this happened just today. Last night I had properly shut down the laptop. I have since restarted it twice today in vain attempts to solve this problem.

Somebody please help me. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

---

**Information**:

Model: Dell G5 15 5590 (2019 model)

Processor: i7 9th gen

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060

---

**EDIT- THERE'S BEEN A MAJOR UPDATE**:

In Device Manager, I unhid all hidden devices, and wallah! The RTX driver is there under Display Adapters. However, it's grayed out.

[image: ITS THERE]

Now what do I do?

---

**MAJOR UPDATE 2**:

It says this in the properties:

[image: Not connected]

Will I need to open the laptop now?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to superuser. What brand and model number is your laptop exactly? (ex. ROG GL531GT)

Comment: @NatsuKage It's a Dell G5 15 5590 (2019 model).

Comment: Just to confirm: you've restarted the pc? Not shutdown. Restart.

Comment: @NatsuKage What do you mean? Last night I shut the laptop down. Then today after finding this out I explicitly restarted it. No results :\

Comment: There's a big chance your GPU has issues then. Or your drivers. Check and see if there's any drivers that were installed before it shut down.  Settings  > Update & Security   > Windows Update  > View your update history

Comment: Is there a key or button on your system that disables the GPU (discrete mode vs integrated mode etc.)?

Comment: @Yorik I can confirm that there is no such button on my keyboard.

Comment: Check the BIOS and or the BIOS-level diagnostics to ensure the discrete GPU is detected. Don't know the keystrokes to open BIOS: it varies from mfg/model/year

Comment: @NatsuKage It says the "hardware device isn't connected to the computer". Will I need to open up the laptop right now? It might void the warranty if I do so.

Comment: @ArihanSharma There's nothing you can do to repair your laptop even if you open it up. If you're sure your drivers are up to date, then I believe you have pretty serious issues with your laptop. You might want to send it in for warranty or repairs.

Comment: @ArihanSharma  Before despairing, I'd try a BIOS update: https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cabsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=5yg2n&oscode=wt64a&productcode=g-series-15-5590-laptop

Comment: @NatsuKage I checked, my BIOS Firmware is apparently "up to date". Thank you for your persistence and dedication towards solving my problem; I will contact Dell and if they can't solve it then send it to BestBuy for the warranty and repairs. Again, thank you everyone.

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/1637521/cant-install-driver-for-gtx-1050-in-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment2501659_1637521).