# cant install driver for GTX 1050 in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

when I installed windows, in device manager my display adapter was named windows basic,

driverpack solution online told me that it couldn't install GTX 1050 driver, and  in device manager, the name of my display adapter became AMD radeon RX vega 10,

after that, I tried downloading the driver from nvidia site(I downloaded: version=461.92whql, for win10 64bit, geforce 10 series -> gtx 1050, windows driver type= standard) and it told me that `this nvidia graphics driver is not compatible with this version of windows` and `this graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware`, nvidia experience couldn't identify my graphics card neither, what should I do?

(ASUS M570DD-B, Windows 10 64bit, geforce gtx 1050)

Comment: “Driver solution pack online” - What pack?

Comment: @Ramhound sorry for not being exact, I meant driverpack solution (https://drp.su/)

Comment: You are sure this card is functional?  Do yourself a favor and never use unofficial driver packs.

Comment: @Ramhound yes I know I did a wrong thing, and what do you mean by this card?

Comment: The card you are asking about. The GTX 1050.  It not being detected by the device manager is a indication the card isn’t functional

Comment: @Ramhound It's in my laptop, there's nothing I can do with it.

Comment: You might want to download the drivers from ASUS https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Home/Everyday-use/ASUS-M570/HelpDesk_knowledge/?model2Name=ASUS-M570 as they may be customised for your laptop. I literally found them by typing your laptop model into Google.